# Why does webpack generate "nvendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js.js" in development?

Tags: webpack

When I'm configuring webpack, the development environment comes up with "vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_getU-317402.js"

configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
  ......
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entrypoint => `runtimechunk~${entrypoint.name}`
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss/,
        use: [
          { loader: isProduction ? MinCssExtractPlugin.loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: isProduction ? '[hash:base64]' : '[path][name]__[local]'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ['autoprefixer']
              }
            }
          },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

result:

```js
asset vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_getU-317402.js 925 KiB [emitted] (id hint: vendors)
asset runtimechunk~main.js 42.3 KiB [emitted] (name: runtimechunk~main)
asset main.js 14.3 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset src/assets/weChat.jpg 178 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 535 bytes [emitted]
Entrypoint main 982 KiB (178 KiB) = runtimechunk~main.js 42.3 KiB vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_getU-317402.js 925 KiB main.js 14.3 KiB 1 auxiliary asset
```

When I configure

```js
splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all'
}
```

it generates:

```js
 vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_getU-317402.js
```

the production environment is normal, And why is there css-loader/dist/runtime related information in the package in the development environment?